# Your canvas page links to a different Facebook URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am getting this error from the review team. But this is not true, i have my website url which after the "Permission process" it redirects to the facebook canvas url from the settings.

Also i am getting:
"Your web platform is a Facebook URL or redirects to a Facebook URL immediately after logging in. Revise your website URL, which is located in the app 'Settings' tab, under the 'Website' section."

Same, not true. After the facebook permission step i get redirected back to the website (not facebook).

Any idea what should i do here? Tested everything, the behavior they are describing is not accurate at all.

Thanks

Comment: In the second sentence you are saying that your website _does_ redirect to canvas after login …?

Comment: I have an argument in the url like: source=canvas and source=web. If the source=canvas then after login it redirect to http://apps.facebook.com/.... etc. If source=web it gets back to the website after permission popup.

Comment: And you made sure that works for both platforms? Are the reviewers instructed to use those URLs including the parameter for both test cases?

Comment: The reviewers are using the canvas url directly for review. Like they go to http://apps.facebook.com/my-app/, the permission popup appears and after that they are redirected back to http://apps.facebook.com/my-app/. Couple of people tested and its working as expected. Also all my other apps are working the same and they were approved. Just this one has issues.